# Trying to put some variables in a shared object, "method or data member not found"

Tags: vba, excel

I have some constants that I use a lot, so I am trying to put them in a shared variable. But when the line reaches `lDayCol = g.lFirstCalendarCol` I get the error message "method or data member not found". How should I fix this?

```
Sub WriteHeadersAndDates(wks As Worksheet, wksExport As Worksheet)
    Dim g As New cGlobal
    Set g = New cGlobal

    Dim lDayCol As Long
    lDayCol = g.lFirstCalendarCol
End Sub
```

The class module defining the global object:

```
Option Explicit

Public bProduction As Boolean

Public ao As String
Public ae As String
Public oe As String
Public aoCap As String
Public aeCap As String
Public oeCap As String

Dim lFirstCalendarCol As Long

Private Sub Class_Initialize()

    ' Production
    bProduction = False

    ' I18n
    ao = Chr(229)
    ae = Chr(228)
    oe = Chr(246)
    aoCap = Chr(197)
    aeCap = Chr(196)
    oeCap = Chr(214)

    ' Excel
    lFirstCalendarCol = 5

End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see now that I didn't define a public way to access that property.